# Is there any possibility to use the same Makefile in CentOS and FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, centos, freebsd, make, bmake

Unfortunately, in some old FreeBSD environments I can't use "gmake", so I need to write a Makefile which will work with FreeBSD make also.
And the last problem I can't solve - use shell commands, for example, I need to get full path to Python executable:

```
PYTHON       := $(shell which python2.7 || which python)
```

But FreeBSD make simply ignores this.

```
test:
     echo == $(PYTHON) ==
```

Then I run make test:

```
$ make test
echo ==  ==
== ==
```

Can anyone help, please?

**Update #1:** To those who can't read closely and accidentally downvotes the question:

Whole test script:

```
PYTHON       != which python2.7 || which python

test:
        $(PYTHON) -c 'print "hello world"'
```

Run on FreeBSD:

```
make
/usr/bin/python -c 'print "hello world"'
hello world
```

Run on CentOS:

```
make                                 
test_make:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

And if I use command $(shell ...) it works on CentOS and doesn't work on FreeBSD. So, is there any solution without gmake?

**Update #2:** Eventually I found solution (put command in backticks):

```
PYTHON       ?= `which python2.7 || which python`
```

I don't know why it prints itself:

```
make
`which python2.7 || which python` -c 'print "hello world"'
hello world
```

But it works! You can use it, guys :)

Comment: Can't you just set `PYTHON` to the correct Python path _outside_ of the Makefile? Also, the use of `which` is superfluous; if `python` can be found in the `PATH`, then just use `python` (or `python2.7`).  Having the absolute path is usually not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *may* be able to do:

```
PYTHON != which python2.7 || which python
```

This works in gnu make 4.1 and bmake 20160220-2+b1

But why bother?  It's honestly probably less trouble to install gnu make and use it, or to write a configure script that generates the Makefile for you with PYTHON properly defined.

Comment: It work only on FreeBSD, on Centos it returns error:
Makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop

15 - number of that string

Comment: @Sergius what is your complete `Makefile`? I can't see line 15.

Comment: I said that number 15 - string with line suggested in the answer. Also, I can't share whole Makefile, but I will share test file.